# This shouldn't have been closed?

Tags: support, reopen-request

[How can I install USB-N13 on Linux Mint?](https://superuser.com/questions/311338/how-to-install-usb-n13-on-linux-mint)

closed as not a real question by studiohack

I can think of no reason that that isn't a valid question. Maybe the moderator in question is less educated about linux and can't understand the jargon?

Comment: You don't have to insult other users on the site.

Comment: Perhaps you could ask why instead? Your Q&A was vague and is unlikely to help anyone...

Comment: I find it too localized anyway. I got the first result on google, and it was a linux driver.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I closed this post because it seemed pretty devoid of details and very broad... It also seemed a little bit ambiguous, to me personally.

However, after discussing with fellow mods and giving it some thought, I've reopened the question, as it is pretty borderline and the question has been answered and accepted.

Comment: Do you use linux? Nearly any linux user would have known what I was talking about... It's very simple. One piece of hardware, for one distro. You don't need more detail than that...

Comment: @NotaName Not everyone is some big Linux expert here, unlike you apparently. Your question was easily answered by using Google too.